# Search for trigger names containing particular variable name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to locate the trigger names which is using `trig_tab` variable.  I tried the below query without the dbms_lob function and  It gave me

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

error.

So I tried using  `dbms_lob.instr` function but still gives me the same error.

Trigger_body field is a long datatype. Using oracle 10g database.  How do I make it work.

```
SELECT *
FROM   dba_triggers a
WHERE  owner = 'BOR'
       AND table_name = 'MAP_VIEW'
       AND dbms_lob.Instr(a.trigger_body, 'mv_pkg.trig_tab') > 0
ORDER  BY status,
          trigger_name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider querying `dba_source` / `user_source` to search for occurrences of a token in the source

```
SELECT name,
       line
FROM   dba_source
WHERE  owner = 'BOR'
       AND TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
       AND Lower(TEXT) LIKE '%trig_tab%'
ORDER  BY name;
```

---

```
SELECT name,
       line
FROM   user_source
WHERE  TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
       AND Lower(TEXT) LIKE '%trig_tab%'
ORDER  BY name;
```